# How to convert raw html to something I can test with Selenium?

Tags: java, html, selenium, junit, automated-tests

My team has created a CMS. When it's API is called by the client (using POST - with parameters), it responds with raw HTML, which is then injected into the client's page.

I am assigned to create automated testing specifically for the HTML (not the client page). On my computer I can save the HTML in a file and open with a browser to test it out locally.

To get the test to run on a build server or through Sauce Labs, I am trying to figure out a way to render the HTML so I can have my test framework grab a screenshot to be compared. My test framework is Java/Junit using Selenium bindings, and I use Applitools for screenshot comparison.

I looked into PhantomJS but got a bit lost in the JS world (I am much more comfortable with Java). Also it appears that these artifacts are quite dated in Maven. If this is suggested, I would really appreciate an example.

I have found topics related to posting to the http endpoint using the Junit approach (leveraging Rest Assured), but I am stuck on what to do with the HTML response and how to plug that into a Selenium test. Please, can anyone offer guidance or suggest a tool to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the data scheme to load the html:

```
driver.get("data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + URLEncoder.encode(pageHtml, "UTF-8"));
```

Though you may be limited by the length and it won't load the resources present in a separate folder.

Another way would be to execute the requests directly in the page and to then rewrite the whole page with the result.

Something like:

```java
// set domain
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com");

// navigate some HTML from a request
navigate(driver, "POST", "/search", "q=abcd");
```

```java
public void navigate(driver, method, path, body) {
  String JS_NAVIGATE_REQUEST =
    "(function(method, path, body, callback){  " +
    "    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();       " +
    "    xhr.open(method, path, true);         " +
    "    xhr.onloadend = function(){           " +
    "      document.write(xhr.responseText);   " +
    "      document.close();                   " +
    "      callback();                         " +
    "    };                                    " +
    "    document.write('');                   " +
    "    xhr.send(body);                       " +
    "}).apply(window, arguments);              " ;

  ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeAsyncScript(JS_NAVIGATE_REQUEST, method, path, body);
}
```

Comment: I like the first approach you suggested, but it seems to simply display the HTML as text... I will give the second approach a try. Thank you for responding!

Comment: @Beth H, sorry I forgot the data type.

Comment: The first approach worked perfectly when I changed it to: `driver.get("data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + response);`

Answer (score 0):

I would save the HTML into a file and use IE to display that file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use badboy tool to capture the screenshots of the HTML files saved locally but this is not including selenium integration. It is just to have the baseline screenshots from the HTML saved locally.

1. Save all the responses in HTML with some predefined naming convention like SS_1,SS_2.
2. Open badboy and pass the path of 1 file in the browsing pane (at upper right) or use "Request" from tools (Drag & Drop) and provide the path of first file saved locally.
3. Put snapshot tool below it and configure to save snapshots.
4. Add variables ${iterator} and provide values
5. Double click on "Request" and change the file name suffix from SS_**1** to ${iterator}
6. Now, configure step to run for each value of variables by double clicking on the step and selecting the second radio button (For each value of variable) .

Reference tool - [Badboy](http://www.badboy.com.au)

[image]